# Disable autosave for Office Web Apps?

Tags: office-web-apps

Is it possible to disable the autosave feature for Excel Web App when working with documents in a SharePoint library?

We are deploying a number of workbooks with Pivot Tables (connected to SSAS), and we're finding that as someone navigates the Pivot Table, its drill and filtering options as saved.  We want to disable that, so everyone will see the Pivot Tables in their original state when they open the workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, it is not possible to disable to auto-save feature. This is one of features which Google Forced and MSFT adopt it.

Did you try to disable from the Excel....may be this one worked.

File menu > Options command > Save option.  Uncheck the "Save AutoRecover info every ? minutes" option

One thing, i am thinking as a workaround... May be give the user ReadOnly permissions so that file open as a readonly.

Comment: That's a pretty subjective comment, 'Google forced it'.

Comment: This feature 1st introduced in Google docs since then a great pressure on MSFT. So far they have PowerPoint n excel Web apss.

Comment: Disabling AutoRecoer has no effect (I didn't think it would, since it's not an AutoRecover save).  Read Only is not feasible in this case, since the users do need the ability to update the workbooks on occasion -- they just need to have control over when it is saved.

Comment: What about adding some slicers or other controls to allow the users to filter the content without manually touching filters?

Answer (score 0):

How about having major and minor versions in the DocLib. And only granting the readers access to the major Versions. That would allow your editors to keep working and the saved wont affect most other users.

If you grant readonly to the normal users you could keep the 2 groups working with the right options.